# Server-side for Next.Js

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, server-side

Yesterday I started to learn NextJs (React) to develop a small site for my family. After passing a learn part of NextJs I realized (if I'm not mistaken) that the framework doesn't have a server-side support, so to say I have to implement a server-side on my own.

SO my next thoughts where what is my choice for the server-side development? I think about exposing NodeJs (Express) API for the NextJs.

Is it a right (good) choice? What are the best practices for this kind of development?

Comment: next.js does offer server side rendering, what are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: if you are trying to use the server part of next, you would use the `pages/api`  files, however when i use next, i usually put express in front of it. so that's a legit option too.

Answer (score 0):

you can explore nest.js for server side https://nestjs.com/
It very modular and with MVC pattern.
Also it supports express by default.